# Try to put single quote inside single quote postgresql php

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql-9.1

this sql I tested it work

```
SELECT
public.pong8_maintable.stockid,

date_trunc('hour', public.pong8_maintable."timestamp8") as Date_hour,

public.pong8_maintable."Turnover"
FROM
public.pong8_maintable
```

This line does not work when I delete this line 
date_trunc("'"hour"'", public.pong8_maintable."timestamp8") as Date_hour,
code will work

```
$sql =' CREATE TABLE pong8_StepOneSection as
SELECT
public.pong8_maintable.stockid,
public.pong8_maintable.filname,

date_trunc("'"hour"'", public.pong8_maintable."timestamp8") as Date_hour,


public.pong8_maintable."Turnover"
FROM
Public.pong8_maintable ' ;

sc_exec_sql($sql);
```

How can I fix it please suggest

Comment: Please read the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) on how to use strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql ='

CREATE TABLE pong8_StepOneSection as
SELECT
public.pong8_maintable.stockid,
public.pong8_maintable.filname,

date_trunc(\'hour\', public.pong8_maintable."timestamp8") as Date_hour,
```

I try this one work

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work :

```
$sql =' CREATE TABLE pong8_StepOneSection as
SELECT
public.pong8_maintable.stockid,
public.pong8_maintable.filname,

date_trunc("hour", public.pong8_maintable."timestamp8") as Date_hour,


public.pong8_maintable."Turnover"
FROM
Public.pong8_maintable ' ;

sc_exec_sql($sql);
```

---

Some tips:

1) Don't have define like if we have used SINGLE quote sowe have to use it all over .

Example `echo 'Hi' and echo "Hi" are same`

Reference : `date_trunc('hour', public.pong8_maintable."timestamp8") as Date_hour,`
Here it doesn't matter if you change quote for HOUR from single to double.

2) **Third type of qoute ( ` )!**
Yes, there is 3rd type of  quote but i am really not sure about do it work  for non-sql statements but within SQL statement id do work.

Comment: Hi akash raigade  I try   pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column "hour" does not exist LINE 8: date_trunc("hour", public.pong8_maintable."timestamp8") as D... ^
Error

Comment: Ok dude te=hen problem is with your Query only   bcas as error say > error column 'Hour does not exist ' then check weather ur last query runs in sql console ?

Comment: If it doent i will try out some more things and update my answer